# How do I wire a Goodman AUX Heat Kit?

Tags: wiring, hvac, thermostat-c-wire, heat-pump

I was installing a new thermostat and had to connect a C wire on a Goodman ARUF for up stairs. While in the attic I noticed the white wires were not connected and I do have a AUX Heat Kit installed. All the wiring from that go to a harness that goes to the control board. There is no white wire externally for the AUX and its white wire goes the the harness. Without a W2 how do I setup the AUX Heat on the thermostat?

Comment: Welcome to [diy.se], please take the [tour]. Then [edit] your question to give us the brand/model of each piece of equipment, and, as an added bonus, clear, focused, well lit pictures of the wiring block of each piece of equipment and the wiring diagrams associated with each.